# Blazor server side application throwing "System.InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. ..." during reload

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I have a file drop zone implemented in one of the pages of my blazor application, which is handled using the javascript runtime interface. In order to avoid memory leaks, I have a javascript method, which removes all the event listeners. This is called from the dispose function as follows:

```
public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    ViewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChangedHandler;
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    return JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("deInitializeDropZone");
}
```

This works, however if I reload the page in my browser (F5, or reload button), I get the following exceptions:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HMI59N5RRGP7", Request id "0HMI59N5RRGP7:0000000E": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime.BeginInvokeJS(Int64 asyncHandle, String identifier, String argsJson, JSCallResultType resultType, Int64 targetInstanceId)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<>c__DisplayClass69_0.<<Dispose>g__HandleAsyncExceptions|1>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<>c__DisplayClass69_0.<Dispose>g__NotifyExceptions|2(List`1 exceptions)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<>c__DisplayClass69_0.<<Dispose>g__HandleAsyncExceptions|1>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.DisposeAsync()
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.<DisposeAsync>g__Await|22_0(Int32 i, ValueTask vt, List`1 toDispose)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.RequestServicesFeature.<DisposeAsync>g__Awaited|9_0(RequestServicesFeature servicesFeature, ValueTask vt)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.<FireOnCompleted>g__ProcessEvents|227_0(HttpProtocol protocol, Stack`1 events)
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the circuit has disconnected and is being disposed.
      Microsoft.JSInterop.JSDisconnectedException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the circuit has disconnected and is being disposed.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime.BeginInvokeJS(Int64 asyncHandle, String identifier, String argsJson, JSCallResultType resultType, Int64 targetInstanceId)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<>c__DisplayClass69_0.<<Dispose>g__HandleAsyncExceptions|1>d.MoveNext()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'blLlOrw1UtfEHUoPBbO_N3peh7u3Or5Uk51p5RbR5xA'.
      Microsoft.JSInterop.JSDisconnectedException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the circuit has disconnected and is being disposed.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime.BeginInvokeJS(Int64 asyncHandle, String identifier, String argsJson, JSCallResultType resultType, Int64 targetInstanceId)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<>c__DisplayClass69_0.<<Dispose>g__HandleAsyncExceptions|1>d.MoveNext()
```

This will only happen on reload, if I switch to another page, the dispose function is called as well, but no exception.
I'm not entirely sure what the reason for this problem is. Maybe it could relate to the initialization as well, which happens after first render:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (await ViewModel.LoadSelectedDatabase(DatasetID))
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeDropZone");
            }
            else
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "The selected Dataset does not exist!");
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"datasets");
            }
        }
    }

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

    return;
}
```

**Edit**: Some more testing, exception is thrown before the `await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeDropZone");` is called after reload.

**Edit#2**: I also switched up the JS function:

```
public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    ViewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChangedHandler;
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

    return JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "testilein");
    //return JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("deInitializeDropZone");
}
```

This will result in the same errors on reload.

Comment: have you tryied to await the js call instead of returning its task

Comment: @spzvtbg thanks for the suggestion, I tried it and change the function to `public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()`, then inside awaited the JS with `await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("deInitializeDropZone");` before returning. However, the issue still remains the same.

Comment: Your JS Interop calls should happen during `OnAfterRender ` or `OnAfterRenderAsync`. This is when the components are in the browser where JS functionality can actually occur.
Take a look at the lifecycle for Blazor components.

Comment: ```await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "testilein").ConfigureAwait(false);``` - configure await false should prevent the task from running when the page is reloaded

Comment: @MoSlo I call the initialization during `OnAfterRenderAsync`, deinitialization is called during disposing of the page component. As far as I was concerned, the JS components (= the script tags) should be in the browser at those times - and they are if I switch to another page. However during reload, my page seems to be deleted and pre-rendered before disposed is called, which probably causes the issue. I'll have to look into it, but thanks for the tip pointing me into this direction.

Comment: @RolandDeschain - on reload you are making new request to the server (all files are loaded again from server or browser cache), but the server is still running and the task remains running on the server but whitout context, when page is loaded the task has new context that differs whit the initial one and this causes the exception.

Comment: @spzvtbg yes, thank you - the question is how to correctly dispose of my stuff in that case?

Comment: have you tryied the above suggestion whit configureawait

Comment: yep, no change :( On refresh it seems the dispose function is called, when the page on the client is already destroyed/re-rendering, causing these problems.

Comment: try catch block maybe, sorry im guessing now, i am working on blazor app too but whit render mode server and was not able to reproduse that exception

Comment: OK, as per [this issue on the dotnet github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29886), there doesn't seem to be a need or a way to clean up js events on full refresh.

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you use GC.SuppressFinalize at all? Are you implementing a finalizer as well in Blazor code?

Comment: @MihaMarkic oh boy, honestly quite some time has passed, but this comes from advice on some forum/docs/stackoverflow post for implementation of the dispose function. I might have to look this up again and review if it is still up to date, but I remember having some error without it initially. Sorry for not being a better help atm but I will look it up soon and report back here

Comment: @RolandDeschain AFAIK you would only use suppression when there is a finalizer defined. Otherwise it doesn't do anything. And you would only use a finalizer when you are dealing with unmanaged data. Which again, I'm not sure whether this is a thing at all when it comes to Blazor. It could be.

Comment: @MihaMarkic actually I think the reason I added it was to prevent the [`CA1816` warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1816)

Comment: @RolandDeschain Sounds like a valid reason :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since it is impossible to call JavaScript when the SignalR connection is disconnected, I believe the recommended way is to wrap it in a try-catch and catch the `JSDisconnectedException` as shown below.
Since event listeners [stop existing after a page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548324/how-long-do-window-event-listeners-persist) there are no memory leaks.
Having said that, I agree this isn't very "elegant" though...

```
async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
{
    try
    {
        ViewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChangedHandler;
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("deInitializeDropZone"); 
    }
    catch (JSDisconnectedException ex)
    {
         // Ignore
    }
}
```

Side note I made the implementation explicit since it is only accessed on an instance of the interface.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Jesse's answer:
I'm having the same issue as OP and currently looking for a proper solution. Seems there's a statement in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-interop-calls-without-a-circuit-1), that confirm Jesse's answer:

Basically:

- try-catch pattern
- MutationObserver on client

> JavaScript interop calls without a circuit
>
> This section only applies to Blazor Server apps.
>
> JavaScript (JS) interop calls can't be issued after a SignalR circuit
> is disconnected. Without a circuit during component disposal or at any
> other time that a circuit doesn't exist, the following method calls
> fail and log a message that the circuit is disconnected as a
> JSDisconnectedException:
>
> JS interop method calls
> IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync
> JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeAsync
> JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync)
> Dispose/DisposeAsync calls on any IJSObjectReference.
>
> In order to avoid logging JSDisconnectedException or to log custom
> information, catch the exception in a try-catch statement.
>
> For the following component disposal example:
>
> The component implements IAsyncDisposable.
> objInstance is an IJSObjectReference.
> JSDisconnectedException is caught and not logged.
> Optionally, you can log custom information in the catch statement at whatever log level you prefer. The following example doesn't log
> custom information because it assumes the developer doesn't care about
> when or where circuits are disconnected during component disposal.
>
> C#
>
> ```
> async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
> {
>     try
>     {
>         if (objInstance is not null)
>         {
>             await objInstance.DisposeAsync();
>         }
>     }
>     catch (JSDisconnectedException)
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If you must clean up your own JS objects or execute other JS code on
> the client after a circuit is lost, use the MutationObserver pattern
> in JS on the client.